# NSInvalidArgumentException... how do I define the arguments correctly?

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting this exception on the following code.  I think it's because I have not defined the two incoming parameter types.  They are local; so how do I define them (and where).

> Error:  2011-04-27 11:18:03.226
>   PointPeek[174:707] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+[SQLiteDB addRecordToDatabase::]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to class
>   0x1fe70'

Here's the calling line of code:

> [SQLiteDB addRecordToDatabase:
>   symbol.data: symbol.typeName];

and here's the method I'm calling:

```
- (void) addRecordToDatabase:data: typeName  {

    NSString *insertCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CardData (CARD_ID, CARD_NAME, CODE_VAL) VALUES ('/%@', '/%@', '/%@')", data, @"Test Card", typeName];
    if(sqlite3_open_v2(cDatabasePath, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: 2011-04-27 11:18:03.226
>   PointPeek[174:707] * Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+[SQLiteDB addRecordToDatabase::]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to class
>   0x1fe70'

Basically, the "`unrecognized selector sent to...`"  message means you tried to tell an object (or class) to do something it doesn't know how to do. ("selector" is another name for method).

You defined your method of the `SQLiteDB` class as an **instance** method:

```
- (void) addRecordToDatabase:data: typeName;
```

We know that because of the `-` in the method name (see [Methods and Messaging](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594) and [Class Interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW2)). In the error message you got, notice that it began with a +, which means you attempted to call a method on the `SQLiteDB` class itself, rather than on an instance of that class.

In other words, you attempted to do this:

```
[SQLiteDB addRecordToDatabase: symbol.data: symbol.typeName];
```

when you needed to do something like this:

```
SQLiteDB *db = [[[SQLiteDB alloc] init] autorelease]; // an instance
[db addRecordToDatabase: symbol.data: symbol.typeName];
```

(Note that the previous 2 lines of code aren't all that useful in and of themselves. Presumably, instead of creating an instance of `SQLiteDB` in this method, you'd have it as an instance variable).

Comment: Ahhh... makes perfect sense to me now... thank you so much!  I really, really appreciate it!  :D

Answer (score 1):

`[SQLiteDB addRecordToDatabase: symbol.data: symbol.typeName];`

That'd assume that `addRecordToDabase::` is a class method, not an instance method.

Furthermore, that is an awful name for a method.  Try something like:

```
- (void)addRecordWithData:(NSData*)aData andType:(NSString*)aType;
```

That is, bare :s are to be avoided and you should always specify the type of the parameter (and not fall back to `id` as you did here).

Finally, why aren't you using Core Data or, at the very least, FMDB?  Raw SQLite is a waste of time.

---

SQLite is harder to write code for than Core Data, most likely.  If you are a newbie to both, Core Data is a better return on investment of your time.

In any case, the questions in your comment indicate that you really need to start by understanding Objective-C.   Apple provides an [excellent language guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

Comment: So I'm really confused now... what is the "call" (or message) supposed to look like?  And, what is "andType"?  (is there a doc you can point me to on how to construct messages and methods?)

Also, I'm not using CoreData because I'm a newbie, need to learn how to code in Obj-C, need to know how SQLite works and with what I've read, FMDB doesn't work with XC4.  I don't want the hassle of XC4 (which is another story) right now... need to get this working...

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head!  I don't understand Obj-C that well... I am well versed in C#, C, C++, and am having one hell-of-a-time getting my mind around Obj-C.  Learning CoreData and/or FMDB (have read on both) will not solve my problem of not knowing Obj-C, tho'.  In the mean time, I have this app to "whip out", and am struggling with it, as you can see.

Thanks for you help... I'll just keep on truckin'... :D